# How to dynamically update edit URL when saving data from inlineNav

Tags: jqgrid

I want to link jqGrid to Web API odata server-side.
When I'm saving data I need to change the edit URL to be like: http://localhost:59661/odata/ODClient(3)
I know how to do it in form edit:

```
.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pg_grid_toppager", { edit: true }, 
    {   
        url: "/odata/ODClient",
        mtype: "PUT",
        onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {
            var selRowId = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            options.url += '(' + selRowId + ')';
            return postdata;    
        }
    });
```

But it appears that inlineNav doesn't have the onclickSubmit event like the navGrid.
Actually from all these events available in form edit - beforeSubmit, onclickSubmit, afterSubmit, the inline edit has only one - aftersavefunc.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is found:

```
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
    beforeSaveRow: function (options, rowid) {
        options.url += '(' + rowid + ')';
        return true;
    }
});
```